# I am getting below error in my sentiment analysis code (Module 'google.cloud.language_v1.types' has no 'Document' member)

Tags: python-3.x

Error in Sentiment Analysis CodeModule 'google.cloud.language_v1.types' has no 'Document' member

```
def analyze(transcript):
    """Run a sentiment analysis request on text within a passed filename."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

    with open(transcript.txt, 'r') as review_file:
        # Instantiates a plain text document.
        content = review_file.read()

    document = types.Document(
        content=content,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
    annotations = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)

def analyze(transcript):
    """Run a sentiment analysis request on text within a passed filename."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

    with open(transcript.txt, 'r') as review_file:
        # Instantiates a plain text document.
        content = review_file.read()

    document = types.Document(
        content=content,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
    annotations = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 document = language.types.Document(content=content,
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
```